# Flutter - InkWell why affect on Margin area of container

Tags: flutter, dart

```
     body: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          print("optap");
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.red,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 200, 0, 0),
        ),
      )
```

Container has a Margin. A InkWell wrapped the container, when I clicked the margin area of the container, the "onTap" method will call, why? I change the InkWell to GestureDector, it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An InkWell's splashes will not properly update to conform to changes if the size of its underlying Material, where the splashes are rendered, changes during animation. You should avoid using InkWells within Material widgets that are changing size.

use [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html), for listening for gestures without ink splashes.

Comment: so Inkwell only can be used on the container without set margin?

Comment: sort of .If there is an opaque graphic, e.g. painted using a Container, Image, or DecoratedBox, between the Material widget and the InkWell widget, then the splash won't be visible because it will be under the opaque graphic.